# react-router-dom can't resolve within project folder

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

When I use `react-router-dom` and try to build, it says it can't resolve within my project folder.

Error message:

```
Failed to compile
./node_modules/react-router-dom/es/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'D:\develop\red\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js' in 'D:\develop\red'
```

[image]

Comment: Have you installed babel-loader?

Comment: I used create-react-app,and I have not installed babel-loader,am I need install it?

Comment: You don't need to install babel-loader then

Comment: Okay,I'm already fix it.I create a new create-react-app environment and it's well now.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Did you already import them?

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'   
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
```

Comment: I forget :import ReactDOM from 'react-dom',I will have a try. Thank you!

Comment: I'm already fix it.I create a new create-react-app environment and it's well now.Thank you!